# Filter out categories in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering how I can query posts that are not in a certain category.

I tried

```
query_posts('post_status=publish&post_type=post&category!=books&offset=5');
```

So I'm trying to get all published posts that are not in the category books, and then I have an offset of 5.

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use -{$category_id}

```
$cat = get_category_by_slug('category');
query_posts("cat=-{$cat->term_id}&offset=5");
```

Comment: Oh I should add.. It should be 'cat=-...', just a minor issue.

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry about that. I was in a bit of a rush.

Answer (score 3):

The [WordPress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/) for `query_posts` is very thorough: [Template Tags/query posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts):

---

> **Exclude Posts Belonging to Only One
>   Category:**
>
> Show all posts except those from a
>   category by prefixing its ID with a
>   '-' (minus) sign.
>
> `query_posts('cat=-3');`

---

> **You can also exclude multiple
>   categories this way:**
>
> `query_posts(array('category__not_in'
>   => array(2,6)));`